# HTML/JavaScript Help using today.getDate

Tags: javascript, html, date, time, web

I'm trying to set up a monthly loop in javascript using

```
today.getDate();
```

However with the code I have below it does not seem to work.

could you tell me why it does not work or help me with a solution

```
var PriColor;
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();

if (dd =< 6){
PriColor = '153, 217, 234, 1';
}if(dd > 6){
 if (dd =< 12){
    PriColor = '0, 169, 157, 1';
}
}if(dd > 12){
if(dd =< 24){
    PriColor = '196, 223, 155, 1';
}
}if(dd > 24){
if(dd =< 30){
    PriColor = '251, 175, 93, 1';
}
}if(dd > 30){
PriColor = '161, 134, 190, 1';
}
```

Or could you perhaps give me a better way of sensing the date in JS?

Comment: I think you are missing `var today = new Date();`

Comment: did you define "today"? I don't see something like : var today = new Date();

Comment: don't delete your question with thanks statement once you get an answer. May be it will help others in future. Remember dear its a community by developers for develpors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define varibale `today` as `var today = new Date();`

**Important**, you are using **`=<`** which is not an operator, use **`<=`**

Complete Code, you can improve it

```
var PriColor;
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();

if (dd <= 6) {
    PriColor = '153, 217, 234, 1';
}
if (dd > 6 && dd <= 12) {
    PriColor = '0, 169, 157, 1';
}
if (dd > 12 && dd <= 24) {
    PriColor = '196, 223, 155, 1';
}
if (dd > 24 && dd <= 30) {
    PriColor = '251, 175, 93, 1';
}
if (dd > 30) {
    PriColor = '161, 134, 190, 1';
}
alert(PriColor);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4UCQA/)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to define "today" variable?

```
var today =  new Date();
[your code]
```